# Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: key must be a string, a buffer or an object

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am trying to build a speech-to-text function using GCP and I am continuously receiving the following error: "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: key must be a string, a buffer or an object"

#### speech.ts

```
import { SpeechClient } from '@google-cloud/speech';
import axios from 'axios';

export async function transcribeAudioFromUrl(
  audioUrl: string,
): Promise<string> {
  try {
    // Configure the Speech-to-Text client with your credentials
    const speechClient = new SpeechClient({
      keyFilename:
        'config/client_secret_206787547924-3a46gf902osirh0h7fm5ud7l6e41mtap.apps.googleusercontent.com.json', // Replace with the correct path to your credentials
    });

    // Convert the binary audio data into a buffer
    const audioBuffer = Buffer.from(audioUrl);

    console.log({ audioBuffer });

    // Perform audio transcription
    const [responseSpeech] = await speechClient.recognize({
      audio: {
        content: audioBuffer,
      },
    });

    const transcription = responseSpeech.results
      .map((result) => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');

    return transcription;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

#### Error details:

```
Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: key must be a string, a buffer or an object
    at callErrorFromStatus (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:81:17)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:356:55)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:454:34)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:416:48)
    at /Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:111:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:326:42)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
    at /Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/build/src/v1/speech_client.js:229:29
    at /Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
    at repeat (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)
    at /Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:118:13
    at OngoingCallPromise.call (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
    at NormalApiCaller.call (/Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
    at /Users/duca/html/sofia/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:84:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 2,
  details: 'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: key must be a string, a buffer or an object',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

#### Disclaimer

It gave me this note saying that this failure **is not transient**, but I am retrying it not even once

Comment: Hi @Duca,Could you please try again after creating a new key file? This type of error is often resolved by creating a new key file.

Comment: Hey @kiranmathew, I created a new key file but the error persisted.

Comment: I have gone through your code but didn't see any issue. Could you  add print statements to your code to identify the line of code that is causing the error? Can you take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-to-text-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs).